# wp-login - unable to redirect user to a custom login url

Tags: php, redirect, login, htaccess

I have this code in a template file that will contain my vue app that I want to load in WordPress.

```php
<?php 
/*
* Template name: App
*/
ob_start();
get_header();

if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
?>
    <div id="app"></div>
<?php
} else {
    wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
    exit;
}
get_footer();
ob_get_flush();
?>
```

I want to redirect users to the login page and this seems working fine, what I need to do is to rename the `wp-login.php` page in `login.php` or `login` and I've tried using .htaccess rewrite rule

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Le direttive (linee) tra `BEGIN WordPress` e `END WordPress` sono
# generate dinamicamente, e dovrebbero essere modificate solo tramite i filtri di WordPress.
# Ogni modifica alle direttive tra questi marcatori verrà sovrascritta.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /mysite/extranet/
# Riscrittura url di login
RewriteRule ^login$ /wp-login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/extranet/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've noticed that this will not work as expected. Is there something else I can do to achive this?

Comment: Wouldn't a `if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {` be simpler? It would avoid the need for output buffers. I'd also suggest using `wp_safe_redirect` since you already know that you're redirecting to a URL on the same install

Comment: Looking into this, the approach of using htaccess, or trying to change `wp-login.php` will never work, but creating your own login page at the URL you want, then using filters to force WP and `wp_login_url` to return your custom URL instead is both widespread and a question that's already been asked and answered on this stack in many forms. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+login+page

Comment: Creating custom login page will imply that I need to create all the needed form fields. I've tried in past uing the wp_login_form() but It will come unstyled and it's not what I want.

Comment: that function isn't the only way to do it, but yes you need to style things, that is unavoidable. `wp-login.php` cannot be moved or rewritten, not without forking WordPress and making major structural changes, that's why there are filters such as `login_url`

Comment: also `wp_login_form` is not necessary, it's just a helper function used by the login/logout widget, not the singular official method of printing a login form. Lots of people build login forms without ever touching that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I need to do is to rename the wp-login.php page in login.php or login and I've tried using .htaccess rewrite rule

> Is there something else I can do to achive this?

No, `wp-login.php` cannot be **moved** or **rewritten**, not without modifying WordPress core. That particular approach to this is a dead end.

*But the login URL can be **swapped**/**replaced** with something that is not `wp-login.php`.*

The commonly accepted approach to this problem is to instead use the `login_url` filter to change where WordPress thinks the login URL is and point it to a custom login page of your own creation. How that page is constructed is up to you, e.g. you *could* use `wp_login_form()`, or construct the form yourself, or use widgets/blocks/plugins/form plugins/etc to do it. There are *many* ways to do this.

This does mean that you'll need to build that custom login page, and style it, and depending on how you build it will determine how much effort is required. How you do that would make a good question on this stack, but there are already lots of questions, and even entire tags dedicated to this subject.

If you just want to see the standard login page that you get out of the box, but at a different URL, then no, WordPress provides no way to do that via configuration/code/filters.